# How to cut two objects of the same type Unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a question. I have several objects that come from the left and right random. When two objects of the same kind overlap, I can cut them .
[image: cut img source]

These objects contain BoxCollider2D and RigidBody2D.

I did come random, but how can I do now to cut them, does anyone have any idea what I could use for this?
Thank you very much .

Comment: Get the two objects from your input, if equals then the cut is valid, else not?

Comment: yes, that's right

Comment: I just need to create this line and they disappear when you cut them

Comment: I'm not familiar with 2D Unity, but in 3D I would create trigger collider for every item going up from lower row, checking OnTriggerEnter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick type up I did to give you an idea of what you can do.

Create an empty GameObject in your scene, give it a LineRenderer, set its positions count to 0(This prevents it from rendering before the player has clicked.) attach this script to it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Slash : MonoBehaviour 
{
    LineRenderer myRenderer;
    public float mouseZ = -2f;
    Vector3[] positions = new Vector3[2] {Vector3.zero, Vector3.zero};

    void Start() 
    {
        myRenderer = this.getComponent<LineRenderer>();
    }

    void Update() 
    { 
        UpdateMouse();
    }

    void UpdateMouse() 
    {
        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
        {
            UpdatePositions(0);
        }
        else if(Input.GetMouseButton(0)) 
        {
            UpdatePositions(1);
        } 
        else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) 
        {
             UpdatePositions(1);
             HandleCollisions();
        }
    }

    Vector3 GetNewPosition() 
    {
        // Method assumes you are using an orthographic camera.
        Vector3 mousePosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePositions);
        // Set the Z position so we can see it from the camera (it would use the same z as the camera otherwise)
        mousePosition.z = mouseZ;
        return mousePosition;
    }

    void updatePositions(int index) 
    {
         if(index >= positions.Length) 
         {
             Debug.LogError("Invalid index was given: " + index);
             return;
         }

         positions[index] = GetNewPosition();
         myRenderer.positionCount = index + 1;
         myRenderer.SetPositions(positions);

    }

    void HandleCollisions() 
    {
        RaycastHit2D[] rays = Physics2D.LinecastAll(positions[0], positions[1]);

        if(rays != null && rays.length > 1) 
        {
            // Checking only the first and second indices of the array, if you want to allow
            // The users to collide with multiple objects this is where you would change that logic.
            // Using name for now, but may be better if you compared them via tag, layer, or gave them a script that defined their type.
             if(rays[0].collider.gameObject.name.Equals(rays[1].collider.gameObject.name)) 
             {
                  rays[0].collider.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                  rays[1].collider.gameObject.SetActive(false);
             }
        }
        positions = new Vector3[2] {Vector3.zero, Vector3.zero};
    }

}
```

Please take some time to understand what this script is doing, and then customize it specifically for your needs.